# Read node Index number in #list command by Apache freemarker template

Tags: xml, list, apache, freemarker

I have an xml file as shown, Now I want to read it with freeMarker template and get the desired output

```
<preDefinedRecipes>
        <preDefinedRecipe type="BREAD" name="A" >


            <parameterDef ref="SUGAR_QTY" value="3" />
                <parameterDef ref="SALT_QTY" value="3" />
                <parameterDef ref="OIL_QTY" value="1" /> 

        </preDefinedRecipe>
        <preDefinedRecipe type="BREAD" name="B" >


            <parameterDef ref="SUGAR_QTY" value="5" />
                <parameterDef ref="SALT_QTY" value="7" />
                <parameterDef ref="FLOUR_QTY" value="3" />

        </preDefinedRecipe>
    </preDefinedRecipes>
```

```
Op needed:
('A','SUGAR_QTY','3')
('A','SALT_QTY','3')
('A','OIL_QTY','1')

('B','SUGAR_QTY','5')
('B','SALT_QTY','7')
('B','FLOUR_QTY','3')
```

But the out put I was able to generate is

```
('A','SUGAR_QTY','3')

('A','SALT_QTY','3')

('A','OIL_QTY','1')

('A','SUGAR_QTY','5')

('A','SALT_QTY','7')

('A','FLOUR_QTY','3')


('B','SUGAR_QTY','3')

('B','SALT_QTY','3')

('B','OIL_QTY','1')

('B','SUGAR_QTY','5')

('B','SALT_QTY','7')

('B','FLOUR_QTY','3')

('B','FLOUR_QTY','3')
```

This is the template

```
<#list doc.preDefinedRecipes.preDefinedRecipe as PDR>

<#assign Name = PDR.@name>
<#list doc.preDefinedRecipes.preDefinedRecipe.parameterDef as PDEF>
('${PDR[0].@name}','${PDEF.@ref}','${PDEF.@value}')

</#list>
</#list>
```

I want to know how to read the index number of the list so I can iterate like a nested for loop. 
New to freemarker , any guidance will be appreciated. thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `#list` should be like this: `<#list PDR.parameterDef as PDEF>`.

The two `#list`-s don't communicate in any way. In your original code the inner `#list` lists all the `parameterDef`-s of the document, and you do that again and again for each `preDefinedRecipe` of the document.